# Get the sum of first element of an array field from all documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my MongoDB collection I have many documents like

```
 { "_id" : 12, "amount" : [ {a:20}, {b:30}, {c:40}] }
 { "_id" : 13, "amount" : [ {a:100}, {b:310}, {c:240}] }
 { "_id" : 14, "amount" : [ {a:50}, {b:30}, {c:30}]  }
```

and I want to get the sum of `$amount.a` of all the documents (here it should return 170). I can't figure out the query to do the same. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "totalAmount": {
      "$sum": {
        "$sum": "$amount.a"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GzGiswZRn_i)

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I'd been using just one `$sum` and there was no output. Mind pointing out the difference?

Comment: First `$sum` is for `$group` accumulator and another is summing the array elements.